# Java String(Query String) manipulation

Tags: java, servlets

I have a strange scenario. Query string has value `first=second=12123423423423432323234`

```
String queryString = request.getParameter("first=second=12123423423423432323234")
```

So i have to:

1. capture 'first' and 'second' values
2. validate the query string has 'first' and 'second'.

Could someone please share how I can achieve this in the best possible way?

I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: shouldn't it look like `first=&second=12123423423423432323234`? Without a separator/delimiter between `key=value` pairs, you're hosed

Comment: This is not a valid query string...

Comment: You need to split by `&` and then by `=` and use Map<String,String> to map the query parameter key and the query parameter value. This is done out of the box by almost all the web frameworks in Java.

Comment: It is a valid query string. But probably it's not what the OP needs :)

Comment: Doesn't this just result in a parameter with name `first` and value `second=12123423423423432323234`? You want to _"capture 'first' and 'second' values"_... what is the value of `first` here?

Comment: @user1635014 : You should respond to comments given by the other users only this way you get right answers :) .

Comment: Thanks Rahu. Will do that? In generally in the query itself i provide my requirement. Anyway the requirements i post here quite weird(i can say business requirements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your query string should look like

```
first=firstvalue&second=secondvalue
```

You can use this in your servlet to print the query string

```
String firstValue = request.getParameter("first");
String secondValue = request.getParameter("second");
System.out.println("Query String:first="+firstValue+"second=+"secondValue);
```

In your case, where the query string is

```
first=second=12123423423423432323234
```

You could do this

```
String first = request.getParameter("first");
String second = request.getParameter("second");
if(first.contains("second=")){
    second = first.split("second=")[1];
    first = first.split("second=")[0];
}
out.println("[First:"+first+"][Second:"+second+"]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters are separated properly by `&` (i.e. `first=&second=something`), then simply `.getParameter("first")` and `.getParameter("second")`

Otherwise, you'd need to play with the string - probably split around `=`, and for the value of first cut until `second` is encountered. Though I fail to see how will that work if `first` has a value: `first=foosecond=bar`?